# Selecting data from SQL Server 2005 DB to Azure SQL staging DB table in Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, sql-server-2005, azure-sql-database

I was wondering if this is possible: I want to create 2 tables in an Azure SQL database which I want to use as staging tables for some data selected from a SQL Server 2005 database on an on-premise server.

Is there any good way of doing this?

**Update:**

Followed the Linked-Server Guide and got this error: [I need to add a linked server to a MS Azure SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28590832/i-need-to-add-a-linked-server-to-a-ms-azure-sql-server)

[image]

The weird thing is i just managed to login to the Azure DB on with Those exact credentials. Am i missing some security configuration somewhere?

Comment: you can create a linked server:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28590832/i-need-to-add-a-linked-server-to-a-ms-azure-sql-server

Comment: Forget to mention, you can select only from onpremises sql to azure sql,not the other way around

Comment: Well i only need to copy some data from the onpremises sql server to the azure server that will act as my staging server. Thank you for the answer, i will look into that one.

Comment: if this is a one time activity, there are many options..like ssis

Comment: Well it needs to happen once a day. Though i am worried i wont get the permission to do this the owners of the database are very careful of modifying the on premises database. i initially wanted to do the staging tables in the same on-prem server but they insisted not to. What other was are there? Just to keep my options open.

Comment: `Well it needs to happen once a day`  you can use replication from onpremises to azure and  you dont need to modify anything

Comment: @TheGameiswar Check the update on the post please :)

Comment: i think you need to create an user in onpremises(sqlauth) and give that user basic permissions in azure,then this will work..I think you are doing the other way

Answer (score 1):

Support for linked servers and distributed queries against a SQL Azure Database is a feature available since September 2012 as explained [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-updates-to-windows-azure-sql-database/). On my tests it does not work correctly on SQL 2012 and does not work on SQL Server 2008 R2 and earlier versions. You may need to upgrade to SQL Server 2014 to create a fully functional linked server.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah upgrading the sql-server is a given. The thing is the owner totally refuses, trying my best to work around the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need to create a linked server to move data from an on-premise SQL table to Azure SQL. Tools like SSIS come to mind, where a linked server isn't necessary. Or a tool like SSDT where you could use the Data Compare feature to move data. There is also Azure Data Factory.

Comment: I see, well its not about mooving data, but more of inserting new data and update the staging table in azure db with data every night from the onpremisis SQL DB. its about 60k rows to one of the tables.

Also i'm using a stored procedure to do this.