# How do I run script remotely on an Azure database without reliance on network reliability

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am connecting to and running queries on an Azure database (S4) which I connect to through SQL Server Management studio on my Windows 10 laptop. I have a complicated query I am running that gives me an select output after about 5 hours but since the database is so large any network problem causes me to get a transport error and lose any output I would have gotten.

if this happened with an on-premises database I would simply put the query in a SQL Server Agent job. But when connecting to an azure database instance I don't see any sql server agent in the Azure instance for me to add a query to.

I would like to be able to run a long running query remotely on a SQL Server  Azure database without being dependent on stable network connection

Answer (score 3):

Put those queries on a stored procedure and then  use Azure Automation to schedule the execution of the stored procedure. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48681024/how-to-set-azure-sql-to-rebuild-indexes-automatically/48683688#48683688) StackOverflow thread I show step-by-step how to schedule execution of a stored procedure on Azure SQL Database using Azure Automation.

Answer (score 1):

Also an Azure VM jump box in the same region as your database is commonly used for stuff like this.