# Azure SQL managed instances

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

If we opt Azure SQL managed instances in DEV,QA and PROD environment .
Will Microsoft take care the DB maintenance in terms of index rebuild or reorganize periodically etc. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure does not automatically rebuild your indexes. You need to maintain the SQL indexes.

There is a blog article on how you can automate these tasks here: https://geeks.ms/davidjrh/2015/10/08/rebuilding-sql-database-indexes-using-azure-automation/

Comment: @Codehunter if this solves your problem please upvote/ accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48681024/how-to-set-azure-sql-to-rebuild-indexes-automatically/48683688#48683688) thread on StackOverflow to know on what scenarios Microsoft recommends to rebuild indexes. See the answer provided by Connor Cunningham (Microsoft).

My personal experience is to do that daily to make sure the CPU, memory and storage space of the database is the lowest, and you don't need to assign more resources to the database. Use Ola Hallengren maintence scripts available [here](https://github.com/olahallengren/sql-server-maintenance-solution) on GitHub.