# Does Automatic tuning in Azure SQL Database reorganize and rebuild indexes?

Tags: database, azure, azure-sql-database, database-tuning

We are looking into turing on Automatic tuning in Azure SQL Database (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-sql/database/automatic-tuning-overview?view=azuresql) and use all 3 available options. Does the create index option reorganise or rebuild the index from time to time? I can't find any documentation on how the index that is created is maintained. Can someone please point me to such documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Automatic Tuning on Azure SQL Database does not do maintenance of indexes and statistics. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48681024/how-to-set-azure-sql-to-rebuild-indexes-automatically/48683688#48683688) a Microsoft Engineer states that in most scenarios is not needed, but in the same forum thread I shared my experience step-by-step with images on how you can schedule a database maintenance on Azure SQL.